# cannot resolve symbol method append

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

This is a snippet out of my code.

```
if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
    String str=sb.toString();
    bw.append(str);
    bw.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

`bw` has been declared earlier. the necessary header files have been imported. Yet it is throwing an error saying

```
Cannot resolve symbol
symbol: method append(java.lang.string)
location: java.io.BufferedWriter
```

any solutions?

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? BTW, there are no `header files` in Java

Comment: Looks like you use a jdk version lower then 1.5, in which the method `append(CharacterSequence)` is introduced

Comment: @GyroGearless BufferedWriter gets append method from Writer.

Comment: the code shall work perfectly fine if the `java version >=5`

Comment: unless he is actually missing an import

Comment: @Jens that is the issue i think. whats the work around to this if i dont want to download a higher version of java

Comment: @mv93 look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java) maybe this is a solution.